# Adobe Reader XI and Acrobat X will not open

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

Adobe Reader XI and Acrobat X have stopped opening. When I try to open a PDF, or either one of these programs, the cursor shows a busy icon for a few seconds and stops.

Each time I open it a process will show up in Task Manager, but no window will open.

I have tried these things, but none will work

1. Restarting the computer
2. Running as Administrator
3. Repairing the installation
4. Reinstalling
5. Following this guide: http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/acrobat-failed-launch-30-days.html
   When I ran acrofix it returned exit code 3
6. Also I have seen, [Adobe Reader XI will not launch](https://superuser.com/questions/591177/adobe-reader-xi-will-not-launch), but I am not running tune up.

There is nothing in Event Viewer for either Reader or Acrobat either.

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

Comment: Anything in your Event Log?

Comment: Where should I look in Event Viewer?

Comment: Try under Windows Logs|Applications

Comment: I went through all the tabs in Event Viewer, but I could not find anything on Adobe Reader or Adobe Acrobat even after opening it and refreshing Event Viewer.

Comment: Do an ALT+Tab to see if there is a user agreement you need to agree to, which might be hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit later, I found my answer. I had this same issue with Adobe Reader and Acrobat. It was not the EULA. I was messing with the task manager and I realized that killing the process acrobat_sl.exe for Acrobat and reader_sl.exe for Adobe Reader solved my problem. I then created a batch file that auto ran everyday and killed these tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Adobe now has an official fix for this problem.
Download [Acrofix here](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/acrobat-failed-launch-30-days.html).

Comment: This is the same link that I posted in the question in #5.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  It was frustration having to use internet browsers to read PDF files.  Until one day, I tried to open acrobat reader XI again and the user agreement came on. I clicked agree and everything is running fine now. Do you remember the user agreement coming on after a successful re-installation?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and this answer helped, thanks! To force the appearance of the user agreement I opened EULA.EXE by double clicking, which should be located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader or a similar path, and accepted the agreement and now everything seems to work.

Comment: This does not look like much of an answer. To make it more like an answer and less like a comment, I think you should rethink and rewrite a bit.

Answer (score -1):

I know I'm late on this thread, but none of the things above helped me out, but I did find a solution to the proposed problem. Since my Adobe would not launch from the desktop, or the .exe in program files, I found a known good computer with the same Adobe and copied the Adobe files from that computer and replaced it with the broken PC adobe files. Adobe works great now.

Comment: This does not answer the question, please don't post your own questions, as an answer to a question. Don't worry the proper thing will happen to this answer, it will be deleted, allowing you a chance to install the patch that fixes this problem